# Configure Meteor mobile app to connect to different server at runtime

Tags: cordova, meteor

Accordingly to [Meteor documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-submit-your-Android-app-to-Play-Store) Meteor server URL is specified during mobile application installation package building.

Is it possible to set Meteor server URL on frontend when the application is running?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit clunky but this works:

```
var app_url = "https://www.other-server.com/";

Meteor.connection._stream._changeUrl(app_url);
Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.rootUrl = app_url;
Meteor.connection.reconnect();
```

When you run this the server will change from the default one to the one specified in `app_url`

Comment: I tried this, but nothing seems to happen. It's still connected to the old server.

Comment: @FrancescoFrapporti Have you disabled your app refresh/hot code reload?

Comment: No, at the time of posting. I did not try after disabling it. My issue is related to this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5639
I hoped that a solution could be to send an hotpush trough the old server making the app connect to the new server (if the container is updated). We ended up making a native fix in iOS and a change to the cordova_meteor_loader in android.

Answer (score 1):

```
var app_url = "http://new.server/";

Meteor.connection = Meteor.connect(app_url);
_.each(['subscribe', 'methods', 'call', 'apply', 'status','reconnect','disconnect'], function (name) {
        Meteor[name] = _.bind(Meteor.connection[name], Meteor.connection);
});
Package.reload = false;
Accounts.connection = Meteor.connection;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the command line "meteor run ios mobile-server servername --port port" but as far as I'm aware this is compiled into the cordova app so cannot be set during runtime from the app itself.